# Performance issues when calling java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo after inactivity

Tags: java, performance, reflection, blazeds, javabeans

I am using a 3rd party library that dynamically creates instances of Java classes and populates those instances with the help of `Introspector.getBeanInfo`.  Certain requests may result in 5 or 6 successive calls to `Introspector.getBeanInfo`.  I have found that when the application is idle for about an hour or so the first call to `Introspector.getBeanInfo` takes a significantly much longer time to execute (20-60 seconds) vs the subsequent calls (< 100 milliseconds).  Calls made within the next few minutes continue to take < 100 milliseconds, but when I wait another hour the first call again takes 20-60 seconds.

In an attempt to re-create the behavior with a simple test application I have found similar behavior when a java application itself is not run for an hour.  For example, if I run the following console app it may take 15 milliseconds to complete.  If I then wait an hour and re-run the application it takes 20 seconds to complete.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Start");
Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyClass.class, Object.class);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("End: " + (end-start));
```

I originally thought the issue may be related to the fact that the Introspector class attempts to create instances of classes based on standard naming conventions that do not exist in my application (for example, `MyClassBeanInfo`), and it was taking a long time to scan the jar files in an attempt to find those classes (my java application has a little over 100 referenced jar files), but I called `Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyClass.class, Object.class, Introspector.IGNORE_ALL_BEANINFO)` using reflection (it is a private method in Sun's JRE which from looking at the code seems to skip the lookup of the BeanInfo classes), and I was still able to reproduce the delay.

I have also searched for information regarding any type of JRE/JVM jar cache, but have yet to find anything that seems to explain this behavior.  Anyone have any clue why this behaves the way it does, and if there is anything I can do to fix it?

As a side note I am using JDK 1.6.0_21 on Windows XP. The 3rd party library I am using is BlazeDS.  My application is hosted in Tomcat using Spring/BlazeDS integration.  I overwrote a number of BlazeDS classes in order to pinpoint exactly where the delay was (which is the call to `Introspector.getBeanInfo` in the `getPropertyDescriptorCacheEntry` method of `flex.messaging.io.BeanProxy`).  Also, BlazeDS does cache the BeanInfo, so calls to `Introspector.getBeanInfo` are only made when Blaze is deserializing an object that is mapped to a Java class that has yet to be processed.  So, I do have other ways to work around this issue, but I would really like to know if there is a valid explanation for this behavior.

EDIT:
I ran jstack on the process multiple times while reproducing the issue (thanks @Tom) and did confirm that it is related to loading jar files. I dumped the threads 5 times over a 20 second time frame (total time of the delay) and each time produced the following result:

```
"http-8080-exec-6" daemon prio=6 tid=0x65cae800 nid=0x1a50 runnable [0x67a3d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.openJARs(WebappClassLoader.java:2704)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2945)
    - locked <0x1804cc18> (a [Ljava.util.jar.JarFile;)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2739)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1639)
    - locked <0x1803dd38> (a org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1517)
    at java.beans.Introspector.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x434649a0> (a java.lang.Class for java.beans.Introspector)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x181bed70> (a java.lang.Object)
```

I can't help but think there is some kind of JRE/JVM jar cache that is expiring after an hour and forcing the jar files to be re-scanned, but I can't find anything online that outlines such behavior.

EDIT:
As it turns out the Tomcat `WebappClassLoader` does cache JAR files and periodically purges that cache.  Now to find out if that cache is configurable in anyway...

EDIT:
Tomcat closes all JAR files 90 seconds after the last time a jar file was accessed.  I overwrote the `WebappClassLoader` to print out when the jar files were closed.  After the jar files were closed I tried to reproduce the delay, but was unable to.  So, this tells me that there is either a JRE/JVM jar file cache, or just something inherent in the operating system (or my machine, antivirus, etc) that is causing slow load times after a long delay.  Still working on it...

Comment: You could try using `jstack` or similar to see where the program has got to. Also, any network connection involved?

Comment: yourkit profiler can save your day..looking in the sun java code is fine and you can learn interesting things but it takes way too much time.

Comment: Thanks @Tom - See edits above after running jstack

Answer (score 3):

At my employer, we too are heavily relying on dynamically generated classes. With the problems of the `Introspector` and how it behaves (e.g. relying on ClassLoader behavior) and trying to load many `*BeanInfo` classes which we do not have, it was a no-go for us and we decided to not use Introspector and reimplement the functionality on our own.

Not sure how much of the BeanInfo you really need, but it may be easier to use reflection and a home-grown property-metadata-information component, which you have better under control. And with easier, I also mean the nerves you will safe once you deploy the app on other application servers, which have their own ClassLoader behaviors and which are even more heavy and unconfigurable than the ones on Tomcat.

BeanInfo and related components are interfaces, so you may even need only to reimplement the Introspector itself and not all your code which uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately, the first suggestion is not an option for us because we are using 3rd party libraries that rely on Introspector.getBeanInfo.  Overriding the Introspector class could be the way to go.  Right now I am leaning towards overriding the Tomcat classloader (which of course would only work in Tomcat, but is sufficient for our current needs).

Answer (score 3):

`java.beans.Introspector` can be a real problem in OSGi environment where searching for **non-existing** classes can be particulary expensive. It's especially true in Equinox  because of buddy class loading: `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: depenent` and  `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: global` can cause serious performance problems.

`java.beans.Introspector` is used in few unexpected places

- `org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter`
- `org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults`
- `org.hibernate.util.Cloneable#copyListeners`

In general, Introspector should be relatively safe in Equinox when `Introspector.IGNORE_ALL_BEANINFO` flag is specified. It's not, beacause in current Oracle JVM implementation BeanInfo caching isn't used unless Introspector.USE_ALL_BEANINFO is specified.  That is, obviously, in direct conflict with the javadocs, so I'd say that this is actually a bug in the Introspector implementation (or documentation).

Comment: I saw that if `Introspector.IGNORE_ALL_BEANINFO` is given as parameter, the classes `*BeanInfo` are not looked up any more. However, there seems that there is no way to prevent the algorithm to look up for `*Customizer`.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, the `WebAppClassLoader` in Tomcat by default caches JAR files for 90 seconds.  When calling `Introspector.getBeanInfo` after 90 seconds I did verify that Tomcat was reloading the JAR files.  The delay was minimal after a few minutes of inactivity, but there was still a delay.  I never did determine why the delay was so much longer after an hour of inactivity.

Ultimately, my solution was to override the `WebAppClassLoader` and cache the JARs indefinitely.  In our scenario this is perfectly acceptable because we are wrapping Tomcat in our own application, there are no other web applications that share the same instance of Tomcat, and we do not allow our web application to be automatically reloaded.  Keep this in mind if you are considering implementing a similar solution.

Here is the code for overriding the JAR caching behavior (`cacheJarFiles` is a custom boolean that I have added to the `WebAppClassLoader` class):

```
private static boolean cacheJarFiles = true;
```

...

```
public void closeJARs(boolean force) {
   if (cacheJarFiles) {
      return;
   }
   if (jarFiles.length > 0) {
      synchronized (jarFiles) {
         if (force || (System.currentTimeMillis()
```

...

```
}
```

Essentially, I am aborting the call to `closeJARs`.  The performance increase we are now seeing is fairly substantial.  After an hour of inactivity we save 10-60+ seconds on new calls to `Introspector.getBeanInfo`.  After a few minutes of inactivity we save 100-200 milliseconds.